# html input validation :valid :invalid

Tags: html, css, validation

I've created an input control with validation:

- required
- minlength = 4
- maxlength = 8

The input's initial value set to `'ab'`.
Since the `'ab`' doesn't satisfy the validation, the `:invalid` selector should work.

But **at the first load** (unedited by user), the `:invalid` doesn't work.
Is there any way to force validation in all time?

```
<input type='text' id='test' value='ab' required minlength=4 maxlength=8 />

#test:valid {
  background: lightGreen;
}
#test:invalid {
  background: pink;
}
```

Comment: you can trigger the validation with `input.checkValidity()` or `form.checkValidation()` on the page load

Comment: `input.checkValidity()` doesn't work unless i modify the text and set back to 'ab' then call the `checkValidity()`

Comment: so you want to listen on the `change` event on every input and trigger itself validation?

Comment: the checkValidity() is always valid if the input was not modified by user

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's always saying it's valid.
Have you tried putting ""'s around the 4 and 8 values?

Like so:

```
minlength="4"
maxlength="8"
```

Can you post more of your code?

Comment: see my sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/textbox-validation-iplhb

Comment: This seems more like a "react" kind of question. This should have been mentioned in the question post prior to posting your react code.

Comment: i tried to implement to regular html + css, still produces the strange result

Comment: Please paste the implemented html+css code here

Comment: here the html sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/test-html-validation-o8pwl?file=/index.html